# How to bind square brackets in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I have no luck binding square brackets in tmux with the following config:

```
    bind-key ] select-window -t :=6
    bind-key [ select-window -t :=7
```

I have tried escaping brackets like "\[", but it didn't help. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with tmux. The problem was in my config, where brackets were binded, then unbinded a [few lines later](https://github.com/vbauerster/dotfiles/blob/ce82a22924236dac29cbaf306ccd03bf0b028ce0/tmux.conf#L157).